How to fix this error in jellyfish android studio: plugin id... version 8.4.0 apply false?
Jellyfish android studio by default downloads the gradle version 8.6.0, after download and running prints this error: Plugin[id 'com.plugin.application', version 8.4.0, apply false] was not found in any of the following sources.
I also downloaded some other jdk versions but nothing works. I don't have any clue how to fix the problem.
Downloaded some other jdk versions with no success.
